# Updating a custom user control in an update panel, from a control outside the update panel

Tags: asp.net, user-controls, updatepanel

I have a an update panel. Inside this is a dropdown list and a custom chart control. 
When the index changes, the chart control updates itself with new data and displays it. 
There is another control which can affect this charts. However, as this other control is outside of the charts update panel, the chart isn't updated with the changes. Not until the dropdown even fires again and the chart is updated.

My question is, how can I get this separate control to update the chart. Do I need to somehow fire the update panel? I'm lost with this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: The method I used in the end was to wrap the __DoPostBack in a register startup script call. Thank for your advise. Your suggestions will certainly come in useful at some point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two options:

1. Set the updatePanel's UpdateModel to `Conditional` and call it`s [Update](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.updatepanel.update.aspx) Method from codebehind
2. Define an [AsyncPostbackTrigger](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.asyncpostbacktrigger.aspx) on the aspx-markup of the UpdatePanel for the control outside of the UpdatePanel